# Repeat array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i want repeat elments in array php, with consider select different element form  array every time for started  repeat.
i have code like this:

```
    $numbermonth=$_GET['month'];
    $year=$_GET['year'];
    $day_list = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
    $days_in_month = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $numbermonth, 1, $year));
    $first_day_in_month = date('D', mktime(0,0,0, $numbermonth, 1, $year)); 
      for($i=0; $i<=$days_in_month; $i++){
       //i want echo here  days names, first day name must be $first_day_in_month 
       // and repeat days yet array is not ended
       echo $day_list[$i];

      }
```

Comment: why don't directly get the day name based on the date in the loop?

Comment: i want get all days name for month! and echo them. this is like monthly calendar. necessary get all days names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to loop over every day in a given month and output the day of the week.

```
$year = 2019;
$numbermonth = 2;

$start = new DateTime('midnight');
$start->setDate($year, $numbermonth, 1);    
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $start->format('t') - 1);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('D') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: in this code first day in all months The same day (Sun).i want code for generate names days every month with the first day : example in the month number 1 year 2014 first day (Wed) I want array days with first day (Wed) for month january. and array with the first day in the month febuary (Sun)...

Comment: There was a typing mistake in my example, it [works fine now](https://eval.in/private/4f0a8a86a96474).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should directly loop the days and get the names but if you strictly want to go after your idea you could do something like

```
$day_list = array('Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun');
$end = end($day_list);
reset($day_list);
$days_in_month = date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2014));
for($i = 0; $i <= $days_in_month; $i++)
{
    echo current($day_list).'<br>';

    if (current($day_list) == $end)
        reset($day_list);
    else
        next($day_list);

}
```

Comment: in this code first day in all months The same day (Mon).

Comment: Sure... If that's not wanted then you need to loop the days like the answer just below by salathe